# How to add the presenter mode to ioslides

Tags: r, r-markdown, ioslides

I know the documentation says to add `?presentme=true` to the URL. I am trying to knit to a local HTML file and I can not add a `?` when renaming the knited file.

Is it something to add to the yaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not rename your file or add something to the YAML. After knit, you may click on "Open in Browser" and just add `?presentme=true` after ".html" in the address bar.

Just to give you an example. In my case, this is at the address bar after opening the `.html` file generated:

> file:///Documents/ioslides-present.html#1

To start presenter mode, this is the new location:

> file:///Documents/ioslides-present.html?presentme=true

Comment: I'm not sure what this accomplishes, because it gives the exact same output (at least in Safari on macOS). If I close the window, it doesn't reopen, if I open another tab and have the same URL they are not in sync. What is this doing?